# How do I change the colors in the hardstatus line in GNU Screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I've got the following in my screenrc:

```
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%{.bW}%-w%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{..G} %H %{..Y} %m/%d %C%a "
```

Which is great, but I'd love to be able to change the colors of the text in the hardstatus line.

Comment: This is more of a SuperUser.com question, since it's not really programming-related. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
info screen "String Escapes"
```

Here's [my .screenrc](http://www.pixelbeat.org/settings/.screenrc) for reference.